# Variable number of partitions and batch for loadDataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, neo4j, cypher

I'm currently using the [neo4j-spark-connector](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-spark-connector) for loading in data from the graph into a DataFrame.
My Spark job contains different queries on different parts of the graph. It can also run against different versions of the graph with less or more data, which we don't know upfront. The problem is that I don't know how to set a correct number of partitions and batch for each query before knowing how much results it will return.

```
val result = neo.cypher(("MATCH (p:Person)-[:KNOWS]->(other:Person) RETURN person.Name, other.Name"))
  .partitions(**partitions**) // PROBLEM
  .batch(**batch**) // PROBLEM
```

I came up with a temporary solution where I count the number of most occuring relationship type and divide this by the number of partitions.

```
val batch: Long = {
// partitions default: 200
println("Calculating batch size...")
val batchSizeCount = if (relationShip == null) {
  neo.cypher("MATCH (n)-[r:MOST_OCC_REL]->(m) RETURN COUNT(r)").loadRdd[Long].collect.head
}

val newPartitions = if (partitions > 5) {
  partitions - 5
} else {
  partitions
}

val batchSize = if (batchSizeCount < newPartitions) {
  1L
} else {
  batchSizeCount / newPartitions
}

println("Batch size for Neo4j: " + batchSize)
batchSize
}
```

Although the overhead it works for most of the (simple) queries. But for more complex queries it does not seem to be correct al the time.
I need to make sure that the reading of source data always uses the appropriate partitions/batch configuration for each run/query.

Is there maybe a better way to define the correct partitions and batch size, without knowing the amount of data it will return ?